# How do I make a parent container adjust its height to match a scaled div using only css

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

in the following code `<span>` has an image which I want to re-size. Also, wrapper should take the height of the resized image instead it takes the size of the original image. Also this problem is only happening in firefox.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <label> India </label>
    <span class="visa visa01"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #dadada none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    padding: 2px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.visa {
    width: 1.6em;
    top:1px;
    position: relative;
}
.visa01 {
    content: url("/images/waww/resume/visa01.png");
}
.visa01:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    width: 70px;
    height:50px;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(0.4);
    content: url("/images/waww/resume/visa01.png");
}
```

Any idea how to make the height of the wrapper as the new height of the visa01.

Comment: Can you edit the question with specifics on why you don't want to use an `<img>` and why the `scale` is necessary rather than just resizing the picture using a graphics program?

Comment: Because I'm not sure I understand the restrictions you're under. Can you use `background-image` and `background-size`, instead of content? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/v7Lhs1ca/1/).

Answer (score 2):

At first glance the issue is due to the `transform` property. I'm not sure why you are utilizing a `transform` property when declaring a static `height` and `width`. Try omitting the `transform` in place of a manually adjusted `height` and `width` (since you were statically declaring these anyhow) and you may no longer have this issue where the original image "container" so to say is getting set dimensions, yet then being `transform`ed afterwards (and the new dimensions now picked up by the `wrapper`).

Comment: In firefox the image is not taking the width and height that i am assigning, thought it is scaling down using transform. 
what is I remove width and height attribute ? @cale